# Multidimesional array pointers

Tags: php, arrays, pointers

I'm building an array piece by piece following a specific pattern.

For example, I have this string `<val0=0, val1=<val2=2, val3=<val4=4>>, val5=5>` and I need to translate it to an associative array. So every time I find `<` I have to create a new array and store the following elements until the next `>`.

The string above should result in something like this:

```
Array
(
    [val0] => 0
    [val1] => Array
        (
            [val2] => 2
            [val3] => Array
                (
                    [val4] => 4
                )

        )

    [val5] => 5
)
```

Everything is working fine for non-multidimensional arrays using `str_split` to break the string in pieces and iterating over them in a `for` loop but I'm having difficulties to find a workaround every time there is a nesting array in the string.

What I need is a way to have a pointer to the last created array inside the main array.

Is there a way to store an array pointer reference in a variable so I could do this:

```
print_r($MULTIARRAY['val1']['val3']);

// prints: array()

$pointer = pointer($MULTIARRAY['val1']['val3']);

$pointer[] = 'AAA';
$pointer[] = 'BBB';

print_r($MULTIARRAY['val1']['val3']);

// prints: array(
//   [0] => AAA
//   [1] => BBB
//)
```

Comment: What s wrong with $multiarray[1][2] = array()? I mean, that's exactly what you want.

Comment: I've updated the question, I'm using `str_split` to break the string to translate into an array and I'm storing everything inside an array using a `for` loop to iterate over the string, and every time the for-loop does a cycle, I have to have a way to remember the last position to store in the multidimensional array

Comment: Well, than don't use str_split. Parse it recursively, token by token. If you encounter < dive deeper, on > step out.. why for looping?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cZ3mU9/2 I will finish my post in 15min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, it's called [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php)

```
$a[1][22] = array();
$pointer = &$a[1][22];
$pointer[] = 3;
$pointer[] = 4;
print_r($a);
```